# Isn't hydrogen chloride a salt, because it is an ionic compound?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, ionic-compounds, salt, definitions

So I just learned in chemistry that salts are ionic compounds.
Shouldn't,
$\ce{H+Cl-}$ be a salt since hydrogen ion has positive charge and chloride ion has negative charge? If $\ce{HCl}$ is a salt then why do we call it an acid?

Sorry if my question is stupid.

Comment: A is B does not generally mean B is A.  Salts have ionic structure when in pure form ( or would have if not stable enough to isolate them ). It is not the case of HCl // BTW, a compound can be a salt, an acid and a base at the same time, like solution of KH2PO4. As being a salt, aan acid or a base are different, not excluding behaviour aspects of compounds.

Comment: Pure $\ce{HCl}$ is not a salt. Pure $\ce{HCl}$ is a gas, and a molecular gas. It is not made of ions. A salt is made of ions. There are no ions in pure $\ce{HCl}$. OTOH, $\ce{HCl}$ does not react with $\ce{CO3}$

Comment: HCl is not ionic. True, it _becomes_ ionic when dissolved in water, but that's another story. Salts are compounds of metals, and there are no metals in HCl.

Comment: "Salts are compounds of metals". Like ammonium chloride. OK. 

Answer (score 3):

Hydrogen and chlorine atoms of $\ce{HCl}$ in gaseous state are covalently bound and is termed [hydrogen chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_chloride). When this gas is bubbled into water, it ionizes completely to give $\ce{H3O+}$ (free proton + water molecule) and $\ce{Cl-}$ ions and becomes an acid solution which is termed [hydrochloric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrochloric_acid). Even in gaseous $\ce{HCl}$, the charge is not distributed evenly. The chlorine is partially negative and the hydrogen is partially positive.

[image]

([image source](https://employees.csbsju.edu/cschaller/Principles%20Chem/molecules/1_7_ionic.htm))

Comment: The free ion $\ce{H+}$ does not exist in water, because it is not an atom : it is a proton, and it is much smaller than an atom. So it is attached to the Oxygen atom of the next water molecule, producing the ion $\ce{H3O+}$

Comment: @Maurice You are correct. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

No bond is completely ionic or completely covalent, [Fajan's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fajans%27_rules). Also $HCl$ is predominantly a covalent compound rather than ionic.

> Shouldn't, H+Cl- be a salt since hydrogen is positive and Cl is negative?

Sure, $\ce{HCl}$ does dissociate into $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ in a polar solvent, but that doesn't mean $\ce{HCl}$ is simply $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$. It is largely covalent. Now you can answer your question. Hope that helps.

Comment: You can find useful  [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here). Like `$\ce{H2SO4}$` leads to $\ce{H2SO4}$